# Send delimited string via JSON to PHP for prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, json, delimiter

For example i send the following id:

```
$user->id = '1{3}4{5}6';
```

Represents:

```
$user->id(=1{3}4{5}6){$option(=3)}$value(=4){$option(=5)}$value(=6)
```

I now need to insert to database using prepared statements **for each** $option and $value pair.

the sql looks as following:

```
    if ($user->attr == 1) {

    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("insert into customers_basket_attributes 
            (customers_id,
             products_id, 
             products_options_id, 
             products_options_value_id) 
             values ('1', ?, ?, ?)");
    $sth->execute(array($user->id, $option, $value));       
    return json_encode(1);
    }
```

I want to avoid falling back to jQuery for each db insertion.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Can you use actual code to show an example of what you need to do?  If you don't want to make multiple AJAX calls, just make one and insert whatever you need to on the PHP end...

Comment: Infact it is pretty simple, i send a ID (1{3}4{5}6) ,1 represents the actual product_id, {3}4 represents a select-menu with options.{3} is the id of the select-menu and 4 is the chosen option.In above case i had a product with 2 select-menus.

Comment: Alright, so you have your own way of serializing your options, and now you need to write something to de-serialize them?  What does this have to do with JSON and your database?  Or are you saying you've already deserialized this data and your query isn't working?  What is `XX?XX, XX?XX, XX?XX`?

Comment: I was only mentioning that i send the id with JSON to php.The one and only thing i send to php is the product id, and if this product has attributes. $user->id, $user->attr , because i have no 2 values yet (XX?XX) i need a way to extract them from the $user->id (1{3}4{5}6)

Comment: i edited the code so you know what XX?XX is now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reggex php multiple instances and pairs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920604/reggex-php-multiple-instances-and-pairs)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand, this `$user->id = '1{3}4{5}6';` decomposes:

```
Product_id = 1
Option_3 = 4
Option_5 = 6
```

and you want to store that in to records like:

```
products_id products_options_id products_options_value_id
1           3                   4
1           5                   6
```

From my point of view, you basically need as much inserts as you have rows above. You may combine that in to one insert with multiple rows:

```
insert into customers_basket_attributes 
        (customers_id,
         products_id, 
         products_options_id, 
         products_options_value_id) 
         values (nn, 1,3,4),(nn, 1,5,6)
```

putting this into a prepared statement is somehow fiddling around with arrays, but should be achievable. Probably its clearer to just issue one insert per row, the cost is marginal anyway.

Comment: Glad you understand the question, however i was more thinking of a function that strips out the $option/$value and do a for each....$sth->execute

Comment: @HenryW So, do that.  It's faster though to do multiple inserts with one statement, as Axel has suggested.

Comment: in order to parse the stuff and split into variables, some REGEX geek should take over, sorry.

Comment: @Brad , thanks for the advice, i would have been already content when i could get the id's out.

Comment: @AxelAmthor i think it is better to make a new question for reggex.

Comment: Seemed to worked out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920604/reggex-php-multiple-instances-and-pairs