# regex php multiple instances and pairs

Tags: php, regex, foreach

I have `$user->id = '1{3}4{5}6';//could be any and more but {X}X are pairs`

- 1 represents a regular product_id but is not needed for the end
  result.
- {3} and {5} represents $option
- 4  and  6 represents $value
- {3}4 and {5}6 are pairs

I require for each pair a db insertion.

How can i take the values out and run the following db execution:

```
//Something like for each ?? as option and ?? as $value do:
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare("insert into customers_basket_attributes 
( 
products_id,
products_options_id, 
products_options_value_id
) 
values (?, ?, ?)");
$sth->execute(array($user->id, $option, $value));
```

***Current code with the accepted answer from*** **Anubhava**

```
if ($user->attr = 1) {
if (preg_match_all('/\{(\d+)\}(\d+)/u', $user->id, $m )) {
 $option1 = $m[1];
 $value2 = $m[2];
 $output = array_combine ( $option1, $value2 );

$sth = $this->dbh->prepare("insert into customers_basket_attributes (customers_id, products_id, products_options_id, products_options_value_id) values ('1', ?, ?, ?)");
 foreach($output as $option => $value) {    
$sth->execute(array($user->id, $option, $value));
}       

}
}
return json_encode(1);
```

**Seems to work for prepared statements.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` like this:

```
$str = '1{3}4{5}6';
if (preg_match_all('/\{(\d+)\}(\d+)/u', $str, $m )) {
   $output = array_combine ( $m[1], $m[2] );
   print_r($output);
}
```

#### OUPUT

```
Array
(
    [3] => 4
    [5] => 6
)
```

Comment: Thank you , was just playing with it, but for regex i did not eat enough cheese :) http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3SB

Comment: Well, actually i need to first find a way to implement it so that it runs the wanted db query.But of course if your methode is the correct way i will surely accept it.

Comment: Oh that is easy. From the code I showed you just need to `foreach($output as $k => $v) {dbInsert($k, $v);}` (assuming function `dbInsert` is inserting an individual key-value pair.